# CBC mode in Firefox ciphersuites strings

Tags: tls, firefox

When viewing Firefox's ciphersuites list, some AES ciphers appears in the following string format:

```
dhe_rsa_aes_128_sha
```

The format does not specify the cipher mode (e.g. CBC). If not specified, does this mean it is CBC by default?

Comment: Correct, it is CBC.